# Parse JSON ajax var

Tags: ajax, json, parsing

I like translate my json-Data to an JS object or assign it to a variable..

```
$.ajaxSetup({
type: "POST",
url: "_class/queries.php",
dataType:"json"
});

var obj;    

$.ajax({
   data: querystring,
   success: function(data){

     console.log(data);

     alert(data[0].vname);

     //obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

     obj = data;

     console.log(obj[0].vname);//<-- prints the expected property 
   }

 });

console.log("return "+obj);//<-- undefined?
return obj;

}
```

the alert print out the right property-value but somehow the eval-function produces an pars error? I've tryed jQuery.parseJSON but wont work either?

Comment: Please show us the JSON data. Also, ajax is asynchronous, so on `return obj`, it might not yet be set.

Comment: Is your json valid? $.parseJSON will work if it is. Id avoid eval because of preformance issues.

Comment: @locrizak it should be valid? [{"ID":"21","vname":"sad","name":"Höbert","adresse":"sdfdsf","plz":"34534","ort":"dfgdsfg","email":"sdfgsdfg"}]

Answer (score 0):

The `json` variable contains already parsed value - the data returned by the server.
Why do you you need to `eval` it?

```
obj = data;
```

is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Set the type property of [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to `json`:

```
$.ajax({
    data: querystring,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        alert(json[0].vname);
        obj = eval("(" + json + ")");
    }
});
```

From the manual:

> "json": Evaluates the response as JSON
>   and returns a JavaScript object. In
>   jQuery 1.4 the JSON data is parsed in
>   a strict manner; any malformed JSON is
>   rejected and a parse error is thrown.
>   (See json.org for more information on
>   proper JSON formatting.)

`eval()` [shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea/86580#86580) if possible - in your case, unless your JSON data contains actual Javascript code to execute you don't need to `eval()` it.

Also, the AJAX call is asynchronous - this means that the AJAX request is made out-of-order of usual program execution. In your code that means at `return obj;` the `obj` variable doesn't have the same value as it will after the AJAX call has returned with data from the server and assigned the return of the `eval()` call to `obj`. The solution to this is [event-driven programming](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/01/17/event-plan/) - in your case, have the success function call the next "event" that you'd like to occur, or use the AJAX function to populate a variable (in the global scope, preferably [namespaced](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/)) that another event polls for (using a timing event such as [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/window.setInterval)).

Comment: thx, maybe that explains why everthing within the success-function works well even obj = data; works! But how can I return obj??

Comment: You must use event-based programming, see last paragraph above.

Comment: one solution is to put async:false as parameter of the $.ajax() – thx for the hints :)